# ANDROID: SQLite with ListViews

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

-- This is my layout thus far for the input --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etClassName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/className"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAssignmentName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="@string/assignmentName"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDueDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/dueDate" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="194dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
        android:hint="@string/notes"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bAddAssignments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/addAssignment"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bViewAssignments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/viewAssignments" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

-- Clicking the add button brings you to this page which is supposed to list the assignment name that you can click to view your assignment --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.63" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNewAssignment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/newAssignment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bdeleteAssignment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/deleteAssignment" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to populate the second layout when my first layout keeps track of the data. How does the second layout know what the user inputted etc in order to populate the listview

I currently have a dbadapter class(with helper class inside), an entry class(creates entry objects), and an assignmentclass(supposed to display listview)

Any Ideas, please?

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  You click the add button and start a new activity, using the second xml as the main layout and populate the list...

Comment: Hard to know whats your actual question. What means 'how to create an entry that lists on the second page'? Also too much irrelevant Code

Comment: yeah its hard to describe, basically i don't know how to post database results on a different page than the one im getting input from

Comment: yes barak, thats what i mean, but i don't know how to populate the list when my first layout is where i get the information and my second layout has no way of knowing what the user inputted

Comment: Ok, so you're saying you need the info from the first page to get the info for the second page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the data you need in an Intent bundle.

When you set the intent, put the data you need in ther next class as an extra (assuming strings here, but can be other forms):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("Data1", data1var);
myIntent.putExtra("Data2", data2var);
YourActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

In the new class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value1 = extras.getString("Data1");
        String value2 = extras.getString("Data2");
    }
    //use your passed strings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is rather vague. I can refer you to one of the [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) Lars Vogella made about how to use SQLLite together with a ListView. They explain everything nice and simple. I am sure that you will find your answer there!

**Update:**

onClickListener of the Add-button in InputActivity:

- Add your user input to the database (with you DatabaseHelper)
- List item Start you second activity including the ListView

onCreate of the ListActivity:

- Create for example an Array
- Let your DatabaseHelper fill the array with the records you want in the database
- Create an Adapter giving you filled array with it

Comment: I did, and actually that is what I was referring to when I said I could only find examples that post the database results on the same page.